# android masking a layout with other layout

Tags: android, progress-bar, clickable

I am using a progress bar in a matched parent layout in my application. Problem is button in the background is still clickable while the progress bar runs. They should not be clickable, so how do I make them non-clickable. The layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_with_fifty_percent_alpha"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_tv_progress_bar_bultenler"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: setClickable(boolean) doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try set this to this layout:

```
    OnTouchListener listener =   new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;//consume the touch event
            }
        };
    yourLayout.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: 'setClickable' method probably works, also setting touch listener is a solution, but I don't want these, I want to know whether there is an easy solution like 'android:maskBackground' in xml layout file.